# How can I pull and store data from a website?

Tags: ios, swift

My school recently got a new grade book software, and personally, I don't like the layout.  I decided that I wanted to program my own, but my only snag is that I don't know how to pull my grades from the website.  All I would need are my percentages (ints) in each subject.  Once I had them stored I would be able to do the rest.  Is there a way to do this in swift?

Thanks so much!!

Comment: First of all the back end server has to have an API which provides the grades after that you can use Alamofire pods to call that API and get your grades.

Comment: Where do I find the back end server with that API?

Comment: If your school have some IT section them may be they can help you with the API.

Answer (score 1):

You can not get website data without API call. You need an API giving data either in JSON or XML, then you have to call that service using Alamofire and there are number of methods to store data like realm database, NSDefaults etc.

Comment: Where and how do I find the data in JSON or XML?

Comment: You have to design your data according to those format. I mean you have to make services to get data from database using server side language (PHP, .NET etc) and translate it to JSON/XML format.